# What's the easiest way to make letters "åäöé" on keyboard with eng_US keymap?

Tags: character-encoding, keyboard, character, keyboard-events, keymapping

I'm Swedish but prefer programming with the US keymap. But sometimes I need to use the Swedish letters "åäö" or the letter "é" which also is used in the Swedish language sometimes. This is a hassle because I can't figure out how to make the letters without changing keymap or googling. I can't use the alt+# method because I use Ubuntu and it opens some menu as soon as I press alt. 
SO either perhaps it would be possible to define the behaviour so alt+# works somewhere in Linux or if there is a way to produce these letters with some other key combination. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you assign a compose key in the keyboard settings and use that in a similar way to the alt+# in windows. [This](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/i18n/compose/en_US.UTF-8.html) page shows the combinations. However it doesn't work as well as the alt+# combination on windows so an alternative solution would be good.